# Is there a more efficent way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Ok imagine the following DB structure

```
USERS:
    id    |    name    |    company_id
     1         John            1
     2         Jane            1
     3         Jack            2
     4         Jill            3

COMPANIES:

    id    |    name
     1         CompanyA
     2         CompanyB
     3         CompanyC
     4         CompanyD
```

First I want to SELECT all the companies that have more than one user

```
SELECT
      `c`.`name`
FROM `companies` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `c`.`id` = `u`.`company_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(`u`.`id`) > 1
```

Easy enough.  Now I want to SELECT all the users that belong to a company that has more than one user.  I have this combined query but I think this is not efficent

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `company_id` = (
   SELECT
      `c`.`id`
   FROM `companies` AS `c`
   LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `c`.`id` = `u`.`company_id`
   GROUP BY `c`.`id`
   HAVING COUNT(`u`.`id`) > 1
)
```

Basically I take the id returned from the first query (companies that have more than 1 user) and then query the users table to find all users with that company.

Comment: What makes you suspect it is inefficient? Have you run the `EXPLAIN` statement on it to see how it is performing?

Comment: Because maybe I can do this in a single join without subqueries.  Whenever I have to use subqueries I think theres usually a better way.

Comment: Sometimes nested queries is the only way to do something, but before speculating, use the `EXPLAIN` command to analyze the query to see how it's performing and go from there.  Try different things and see how the average execution times vary.

Comment: If the code/query works, and you want to improve it, then it belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and not on [so].

Comment: Why are you using an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Comment: Also - please always explicitly list all columns in a `SELECT` list.  And be aware that MySQL's decision to _not_ require all columns to be in the `GROUP BY` clause/an aggregate function can generate incorrect (more like left out) results.  It works here because the results are unique, but you're better off putting columns in one of those places.  Pretty much all other RDBMSs throw syntax errors for the first query, to avoid the potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
SELECT * FROM users u GROUP BY u.company_id HAVING COUNT(u.id) > 1
```

You don't really need any information from the companies table according to the data you say needs returning. "Now I want to SELECT all the users that belong to a company that has more than one user."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.company_id FROM users u
inner join companies c on u.company_id = c.id
group by c.id
having count(u.id) > 1
```

Comment: Um, this is only going to return one row per company, right?  Due to grouping by `c.id`? So you get a random user name for each company that has more than one user, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get the users only is probably to keep the subquery but eliminate the join; since it's not a correlated subquery, it should be fairly efficient (obviously an index on company_id helps here);

```
SELECT u.* FROM USERS u WHERE company_id IN (
  SELECT company_id FROM USERS GROUP BY company_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1
);
```

You *could* for example rewrite it as a `LEFT JOIN`, but I suspect it will actually be less efficient since you'd most likely need to use a `DISTINCT` when using a `JOIN`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN USERS u2
  ON u.company_id=u2.company_id AND u.id<>u2.id
WHERE u2.id IS NOT NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cbf4/4).

Answer (score 0):

Try also a semi-join query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM users u1
  WHERE u.company_id=u1.company_id
    AND u.id <> u1.id
)
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12dc34/2

Assumming that `id` is a primary key column, creating an index on `company_id` column gives better performance.
If you are really obsessed with the performance of this query, create a composite index on columns company_id + id:

```
CREATE INDEX very_fast ON users( company_id, id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT company_id
    FROM users
    GROUP BY company_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) x USING(company_id);
```

You should have an index `INDEX(company_id)`

## Peformance Test

I have tested 3 queries in answers.

1. Q1 = sub-query (with GROUP BY) and INNER JOIN
2. Q2 = LEFT JOIN and IS NOT NULL
3. Q3 = EXISTS

All queries return same result. Test was done with TPC-H `lineitem` table. And The problem is *"find lineitem have more than 1 item"*

### Test Results

It depends on what you want is retrieving FIRST N row or entire rows.

- Q1 (get FIRST 10K rows) : 2.85 sec
- Q2 (get FIRST 10K rows) : 0.03 sec
- Q3 (get FIRST 10K rows) : 0.03 sec
- Q1 (get all rows) : 8.19 sec
- Q2 (get all rows) : 34.12 sec
- Q3 (get all rows) : 29.54 sec

### Schema and DATA

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM lineitem\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
COUNT(*): 11997996
1 row in set (1.68 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE lineitem\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: lineitem
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `lineitem` (
  `l_orderkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_partkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_suppkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_linenumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_quantity` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `l_extendedprice` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `l_discount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `l_tax` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `l_returnflag` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `l_linestatus` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `l_shipDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `l_commitDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `l_receiptDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `l_shipinstruct` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `l_shipmode` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `l_comment` varchar(44) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`l_orderkey`,`l_linenumber`),
  KEY `l_orderkey` (`l_orderkey`),
  KEY `l_partkey` (`l_partkey`,`l_suppkey`),
  CONSTRAINT `lineitem_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`l_orderkey`) REFERENCES `orders` (`o_orderkey`),
  CONSTRAINT `lineitem_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`l_partkey`, `l_suppkey`) REFERENCES `partsupp` (`ps_partkey`, `ps_suppkey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Queries

**Q1 FIRST 10K**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT u.l_orderkey, u.l_linenumber
FROM lineitem u INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT  l_orderkey
    FROM lineitem
    GROUP BY l_orderkey
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) x USING (l_orderkey)
LIMIT 10000;
```

**Q2 FIRST 10K**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT u.l_orderkey, u.l_linenumber
FROM lineitem u
LEFT JOIN lineitem u2
  ON u.l_orderkey=u2.l_orderkey AND u.l_linenumber<>u2.l_linenumber
WHERE u2.l_linenumber IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 10000;
```

**Q3 FIRST 10K**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT u.l_orderkey, u.l_linenumber
FROM lineitem u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM lineitem u1
  WHERE u.l_orderkey=u1.l_orderkey
    AND u.l_linenumber <> u1.l_linenumber
)
LIMIT 10000;
```

### retrieve entire rows

**Q1 ALL**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM lineitem u INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT  l_orderkey
    FROM lineitem
    GROUP BY l_orderkey
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) x USING (l_orderkey);
```

**Q2 ALL**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM lineitem u
LEFT JOIN lineitem u2
  ON u.l_orderkey=u2.l_orderkey AND u.l_linenumber<>u2.l_linenumber
WHERE u2.l_linenumber IS NOT NULL;
```

**Q3 ALL**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*)
FROM lineitem u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM lineitem u1
  WHERE u.l_orderkey=u1.l_orderkey
    AND u.l_linenumber <> u1.l_linenumber
);
```